# Batch File Loop Through Specfied Folders

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, directory

This should be so simple - annoyed with myself that I'm struggling. I'm trying to write a batch file which copies files to the local computer from a network share so we can access them for offline use. Simple when I want to copy all of the files / folders (below) but I get stuck when I only want to copy certain folders from the specified directory.

```
set dst="C:\Users\Public\Test Dest"
set src="Z:\Blah & Blah\Foo Bar"
robocopy %src% %dst% /S /MT4 /NFL /NDL /NP /NS /NC /MIR
```

for copying everything - works fine. But if I only want to copy 'Folder 1', 'Folder 2' and 'Folder 3' from src and put them in folders of the same name in dest I get stuck.

```
EG:
Foo Bar:
Folder 1
  Copy this.txt
Folder 2
  Copy this.txt
Folder 3
  Copy this.txt
Folder 4
  Don't copy this.txt
Don't copy this.txt
```

So dest would become

```
Test Dest:
Folder 1
  Copy this.txt
Folder 2
  Copy this.txt
Folder 3
  Copy this.txt
```

I have removed the actual copy for the purposes of testing and are just trying to print the full source and dest which I can just throw in the copy later (I hope). Here's what I got:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set dst="C:\Users\Public\Test Dest"
set src="Z:\Blah & Blah\Foo Bar"

echo %dst%
echo %src%

set FOLDER_LIST=("Folder 1" "Folder 2" "Folder 3")
for %%i in %FOLDER_LIST% do (
 echo %src%\%%i
)
```

This echos src and dst correctly, if is when I try to combine them with the folder and backslash in the loop I struggle. Any hints?

Alternatively I could read the folder list from a text file rather than hard coding it in (folder names on new lines) - which would be a prefered solution as it would make editing easier.

I have tried a few things such as setting a new variable inside the loop, !, % and %% etc, but I can't say I fully understand what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I jumped the gun a bit: far easier to read from a file...

```
set "fldr=Use Folders.txt"

for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("%fldr%") do (
    echo %src%\%%i
)
```